# Apple Script - append text to note with new line

Tags: icloud, applescript, notes.app, html

I am having a little trouble appending Text to a Apple Note.

```
set AppendedText to (the clipboard)

###################################

tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Clipboard"
            set OriginalText to the body of every note -- There's only one note in this folder
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

# the OriginalText variable represents the text of the note in HTML form
###################################

tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        tell folder "Clipboard"
            set body of every note to {"<div><span style=\"font-size: 18px\">" & OriginalText & "</span></div><div><span style=\"font-size: 18px\"><br></span></div><div><span style=\"font-size: 18px\">" & AppendedText & "</span></div>"}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

The only problem is that if I copy text with line breaks, indented sections, and other line formatting, such as the following text...

```
tell application Notes
    tell account iCloud
        tell folder Clipboard
        blah blah blah
end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

...and then run the script, the text is appended like this: `tell application Notes tell account iCloud tell folder Clipboard blah blah blah end tell end tell end tell`

**How do I preserve the line formatting of the appended text?** Presumably this involves the use of HTML tags

(Also, I *DO* want all the text to formatted as 18 points in size, as shown in the script.)

Comment: How is the `AppendedText` being placed on the _clipboard_?  Copied from where?

Comment: I selected it from within another note in  the Apple notes app, and entered the command-C keyboard shortcut. @user3439894

Comment: Will that always be the case?

Comment: No, but I can test if the formatting is even saved to the clipboard in the first place by adding `display dialog AppendedText`@user3439894

Comment: Is there a way to apply HTML formatting to text that is represented by a variable? @@user3439894